# How to find definitions of descendant classes including anonymous ones in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, class-hierarchy

Class hierarchy shows named class definitions only (apparently).

Class usage shows any usage, including variable and function parameters definitions.

Is it possible to find only derived class definitions, but including anonymous classes too?

**UPDATE**

Was my fault: hierarchy shows anon descending too...

Comment: `Ctrl` + `H` shows the hierarchy which includes both inner and anonymous classes: [sample](http://imgur.com/a/QcMgd). What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean the implementation icon in the left gutter?  Doesn't that show all implementations of a class or interface?

Comment: @Morfic it was me who was missing something :)

Comment: No problem, it happens once in a while. Do you want me to post an answer for future generations (or post one yourself), or do you plan on deleting the question?